# CSS infinite scrolling div

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Hi i am trying to make the div to scroll with a simple css animation.

The problem is that it doesn't loop good, because there is a little flash before to restart scrolling.

**HERE IS THE CODE:** https://jsfiddle.net/by6tx4o0/2/

```css
.c{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  max-height:200px;
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.card-home{
  position:absolute;
  margin:20px;
 top:0;
   animation: scroll 10s linear 1s infinite;
}
span {
  min-width:300px;
  min-height:40px;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  margin:5px;
  background:blue;
}
@keyframes scroll {
 100% { top: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="c">sssss
<div class="card-home">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
</div>
</div>
```

What do i have to do to make this smooth when looping?

thank you

Comment: Please put code in the question rather than trying to get around it :-)

Comment: jsfiddle attached, look

Comment: It seems like it just instantly goes up to the top when restarting. If you want you can basically do the reverse animation much faster to get it to the top.

Comment: @VictorVH i don't understand very well , what you mean by reverse animation ?

Comment: @blastabam we know the code is there, but people want to glance at the code to see if they can help before they press the link, it's why the rules say you need to put code in your question if you have a jsfiddle link.

Comment: @blastabam do the exact same animation you do to make it scroll down, just make it scroll upwards, and make it do it faster

Comment: Code > jsfiddle, besides Stack Overflow has its own code interpreter if you looked carefully enough.

Comment: done with the code ......

Comment: @VictorVH i need it smooth not fast.... the speed is ok as i need it ;)

Comment: @blastabam As i understand the question, you are complaining that it instantly jumps up to the top when it is reaching the bottom right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hmmm a tricky one and will need a few hard coded values if you want it to be pure css but here is the gist of it:

```css
.c{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  max-height:225px;  /*height to show an exact number of spans  - in this case span is 45px (40 height plus 5 margin as margins collapse) and we are showing 5 spans to start */
  float:left;
  width:315px;
  height:225px;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.card-home{
  position:absolute;
 top:0;
   animation: scroll 10s linear 1s infinite;
}
span {
  min-width:290px;
  min-height:40px;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  margin:5px;
  background:blue;
}
@keyframes scroll {
 100% { top: -360px; }  /* top is the number of spans (in this case 8) multiplied by span height (45px as described above)*/
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
<div class="card-home">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <!-- copy the number of spans displayed at the beggining onto the end -->
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Also I would move that `ssss` text outside the scroller so that the top 20px margin you started with doesn't interfere with the scroller

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have it scrolling smoothly to the top once the animation is complete, one thing that you could do is just modify a little bit your animation, so instead of finishing at the bottom, it finishes at the top (that is the original state so there won't be any "jump" when the animation restarts).

You can do this by:

- Scrolling to the bottom using 95% of the animation time.
- Using the 5% remaining to scroll up.

The code changes would be really simple, and it would not require any JavaScript:

```
@keyframes scroll {
    95% { top: -100%; }
    100% { top:0; }
}
```

---

This demo shows the result:

```css
.c{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  max-height:200px;
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.card-home{
  position:absolute;
  margin:20px;
  top:0;
  animation: scroll 10s linear 1s infinite;
}
span {
  min-width:300px;
  min-height:40px;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  margin:5px;
  background:blue;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  95% { top: -100%; }
  100% { top:0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="c">sssss
<div class="card-home">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
</div>
</div>
```