# How do I make the text scroll continously

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, slide

I have no code to show yet because I have no idea how to do that... my question is: How do I make the text scroll continously i.e., as soon the line 9 is getting up, rather  show the blank space, show the contents of line 1 and so on, so there's no empty space. I supposed to do that with JS, I guess but I don't know how to get those offsets or show the contents from top right after the bottom lines is moving up... my current code goes like this:

```css
#jobs_container {
  background: transparent;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-style: dashed;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#jobs_header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
#jobs_header_left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}
#jobs_header_left > span {
  padding-right: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  color: #0048FF;
}
#jobs_header_center {
    text-align: center;
    font: 20px Verdana;
    color: darkblue;
}

#jobs_header_right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}
#jobs_today {
  margin-inline: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0048FF;
}
#jobs_nextButton {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#jobs_prevButton {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  padding: 0px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#jobs_content {
  font-style: calibre;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 300px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#jobs_content #jobs_listOfEvents {
    overflow: hidden;
    animation-name: jobs_agendaSlide;
    animation-duration: 25s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    position: relative;
}

#jobs_listOfEvents:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes jobs_agendaSlide {
    from {
        top: 10px;
    }
    
    to {
        top: -200px;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div id="jobs_container">
    <div id="jobs_header">
      <div id="jobs_header_left">
      </div>
      <div id="jobs_header_center">
        Center text
      </div>
      <div id="jobs_header_right">
      </div>
    </div>
      <div id="jobs_content">
          <div id="jobs_listOfEvents">
            line1<hr>
            line2<hr>
            line3<hr>
            line4<hr>
            line5<hr>
            line6<hr>
            line7<hr>
            line8<hr>
            line9<hr>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS infinite scrolling div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314474/css-infinite-scrolling-div)

Comment: What behaviour do you want from the scroll bar? Have you found any examples of this online?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti the effect is just like this but I'd like to make it work with variable content (so the fixed sizes seems to not solve my issue)

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert the external effect similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314474/css-infinite-scrolling-div as Sigurd pointed but but I'd like to make it work with variable content (so the fixed sizes seems to not solve my issue)