Slide client logo from right to left infinite loop
I am using the code below for my client's logo. This code creates an infinite slider that slides from right to left.
I am also using jQuery to append duplicate slides for the infinite loop.
However, I'm encountering an issue: the code resets automatically after the slide reaches the fourth card.
would you help me out what is the issue here?


 $(document).ready(function() {
    // Clone cards to create infinite loop
    $(".marqueme").clone().appendTo(".marquestarthere");

  });
 .testimonial-cards {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 56px 31px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: max-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.testimonial-cards li {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.marqueslide .marqueme {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border:1px solid #000
}


/* solution */

.marquestarthere {
  animation: marquee 8s linear infinite; /* Set the animation here */
}

.marquestarthere:hover{
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0%,100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  99.999% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
<div class="marqueslide">
    <ul class="testimonial-cards marquestarthere">

    <li class="marqueme">Card 1</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 2</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 3</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 4</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 5</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 6</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 7</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 8</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 9</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 10</li>

    <!-- duplicate cards append here-->
</ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>




I answered a similar question yesterday - does anything in there help?

@ITgoldman, I haven't understood you comment.

@JaromandaX, Checking your answer

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314474/css-infinite-scrolling-div



 $(document).ready(function() {
    // Clone cards to create infinite loop
    $(".marqueme").clone().appendTo(".marquestarthere");

  });
 .testimonial-cards {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 56px 31px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: max-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.testimonial-cards li {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
   aspect-ratio: 1/1;
   
}

.marqueslide .marqueme {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border:1px solid #000
}


/* solution */

.marquestarthere {
  animation: marquee 8s linear infinite; /* Set the animation here */
}

.marquestarthere:hover{
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0%,100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  99.999% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
<div class="marqueslide">
    <ul class="testimonial-cards marquestarthere">

    <li class="marqueme">Card 1</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 2</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 3</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 4</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 5</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 6</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 7</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 8</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 9</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 10</li>

    <!-- duplicate cards append here-->
</ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>



it's an issue with the width of the cards, if the card container is sliding 50% it isn't able to get to last card by time the animation ends, removing the width: 100% from li seems to work, you can size it as required  but might need to change the translateX value appropriately.



        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Clone list items to create infinite loop
            $(".marqueslide .marqueme").slice(0, 4).clone().appendTo(".marquestarthere");
        });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marqueslide">
    <ul class="testimonial-cards marquestarthere">
        <li class="marqueme">Card 1</li>
        <li class="marqueme">Card 2</li>
        <li class="marqueme">Card 3</li>
        <li class="marqueme">Card 4</li>
        <!-- Duplicate list items will be appended here -->
    </ul>
    </div>



The issue you're encountering seems to be related to the way you're appending the duplicate slides. It looks like you're cloning the entire .marqueme element and appending it to .marquestarthere, which is causing duplication of the entire list. Instead, you should only clone the individual list items and append them accordingly.
Here's the corrected jQuery code to clone and append the list items properly:
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Clone list items to create infinite loop
    $(".marqueslide .marqueme").slice(0, 4).clone().appendTo(".marquestarthere");
});

And here's the corrected HTML structure:
<div class="marqueslide">
<ul class="testimonial-cards marquestarthere">
    <li class="marqueme">Card 1</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 2</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 3</li>
    <li class="marqueme">Card 4</li>
    <!-- Duplicate list items will be appended here -->
</ul>

This code will clone the first four list items (cards) and append them to the end of the list, creating the infinite loop effect you desire.

Can you please create your code in the snippet section to check the output? i have tried you Js but it's not working.

Slider code not working in your snippet.
